# given a unit test that make sure that prevent wrong-assigned values in a class argument, how to write a method that takes that into account?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, tdd

I'm introduced recently to Test Driven Development. However, I am having a hard time understanding it.  The following unit test is a given:

```
public void Setup()
{
    invoicePosition = new InvoicePosition{
        Customer = new Customer(),
        ItemIdentifier = 0,
        ItemName = "SpringRoll",
        Orders = 2,
        SingleUnitPrice = 3.50m
    };

    pairs = new KeywordPair[]{
        new KeywordPair(new Keyword("ItemNumber"),invoicePosition.ItemIdentifier.ToString()),
        new KeywordPair(new Keyword("ItemName"), invoicePosition.ItemName),
        new KeywordPair(new Keyword("CustomerName"), invoicePosition.Customer.Name),
        new KeywordPair(new Keyword("AmountOrdered"), invoicePosition.Orders.ToString()),
        new KeywordPair(new Keyword("NetPrice"), invoicePosition.SingleUnitPrice.ToString())
    };
}

[Test]
public void Invoice_CreateOrderOrderedInput_Valid(){
    var invoice = InvoicePosition.CreateFromPairs(pairs);
    Assert.AreEqual(invoicePosition.ItemIdentifier, invoice.ItemIdentifier);
    Assert.AreEqual(invoicePosition.ItemName.GetType(), invoice.ItemName.GetType());
    Assert.AreEqual(invoicePosition.Customer.Name, invoice.Customer.Name);
    Assert.AreEqual(invoicePosition.Orders, invoice.Orders);
    Assert.AreEqual(invoicePosition.SingleUnitPrice, invoice.SingleUnitPrice);
}
```

Please note that Keyword and Keyword structs are as follows:

```
public struct Keyword
{
        private string keyword;
        private KeywordTypes type;

        public Keyword(string keyword, KeywordTypes Type = KeywordTypes.String){
            this.keyword = keyword;
            this.type = Type;
}

public struct KeywordPair
{
        public Keyword Key;
        public string Value;

        public KeywordPair(Keyword key, string value)
        {
            this.Key = key;
            this.Value = value;
        }
}
```

now I have written the following project for the previous unit test:
namespace SimpleShop

```
    public class InvoicePosition
    {
        public uint ItemIdentifier = 0;
        public string ItemName = "";
        public uint Orders = 0;
        public decimal SingleUnitPrice = 0.0m;
        public Customer Customer;
        public KeywordPair[] Pairs = new KeywordPair[0];

        public static InvoicePosition CreateFromPairs(KeywordPair[] pairs)
        {
            var invoice = new InvoicePosition();
            invoice.Pairs = pairs;
            return invoice;
        }          
    }
```

I need to write code that accounts for wrong serializations. for example, what if pairs is introduced to the program as follows:

```
pairs[3] = new KeywordPair(new Keyword("AmountOrdered"), "+%&/" + invoicePosition.Orders.ToString());
pairs[4] = new KeywordPair(new Keyword("NetPrice"), invoicePosition.SingleUnitPrice.ToString() + 
"%&öä/");
```

thank you, any help would be great.

Comment: Don't test test objects. Test the actual code. For such cases, I might load JSON "as it would be done". Using a Test Case Source, one can supply a number of JSON inputs and expected object outputs.

Comment: I might use this advanced tool in the future. As a beginner, I suppose the instructor needs us to use primitive functions to see our understanding of the fundamental concepts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the test `Invoice_CreateOrderOrderedInput_Valid`, the `InvoicePosition` suggested in the OP **does not pass the test**. By using Visual Studio's various refactoring tools, something like this is *the simplest thing that could possibly work:*

```
public class InvoicePosition
{
    public Customer Customer { get; set; }
    public int ItemIdentifier { get; set; }
    public string ItemName { get; set; }
    public int Orders { get; set; }
    public decimal SingleUnitPrice { get; set; }

    public static InvoicePosition CreateFromPairs(KeywordPair[] pairs)
    {
        return new InvoicePosition
        {
            ItemName = "",
            Customer = new Customer(),
            Orders = 2,
            SingleUnitPrice = 3.5m
        };
    }
}
```

The `CreateFromPairs` implementation is clearly not the full or correct implementation, but it passes all tests. The challenge with TDD is to figure out which test to write next.

TDD works best if you can move forward in as small steps as possible. You might want to consider the [Transformation Priority Premise](http://blog.cleancoder.com/uncle-bob/2013/05/27/TheTransformationPriorityPremise.html). Which part of the incorrect implementation would you first like to address?

Perhaps you're unhappy that `ItemName` is hard-coded to the empty string. How can you write a new test that encourages you to make the implementation more general?

I'd write another test that keeps everything from the first test constant, *except* the `ItemName` value.

The way the test is currently structured, with its big `Setup` method, makes that inconvenient. I recommend that you look into writing [parametrised tests](http://xunitpatterns.com/Parameterized%20Test.html) instead.